# For future reference on getelementbyID in Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementbyid

What objects can you not add the “onclick” to by using getelementbyID method?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `onclick` event listener only to `HTMLElement`s. In fact, `onclick` is defined (as a getter/setter) in `HTMLElement.prototype.onclick`.

With `document.getElementById` you can get `Element`s in the DOM that have an `id`.

Therefore,

- You can't use `onclick` on objects which are not `HTMLElement`s.
- You can use it on `HTMLElement` instances, but you won't be able to get them using `document.getElementById` if they have no `id` or if they aren't in the DOM.